# Проблемы после подключения ОЗУ в ноутбук

Tags: ноутбук

Ребят, привет. У меня ноутбук lenovo ideapad 320   и там стоит 4 гб ddr3, я купил Samsung ОЗУ на 8 гиг ddr3 и когда установил при включении черный экран и только кнопка включения горит. Вообще понять не могу почему не работает.
Был бы благодарен за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может недощелкнул

Comment: PC3L на старой, PC3 на новой

Comment: Получается pc3l это как lpddr3, а pc3 это ddr3?

Comment: Ага, ещё частоты нужно посмотреть какие поддерживает чипсет и проц

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое. Так тонко с покупкой ОЗУ нужно быть( Изучил перед покупкой, но что то не то купил (

Comment: на большинстве компьютеров можно воткнуть любую память. так как  но, например, память от AMD не подходит к процессорам AMD серии A.

Comment: и обязательно отключай питание и батарейку когда вставляешь память. может сгореть